# Optimizing a piecewise-linear, convex function

Tags: python, optimization, loss-functions, scipy

I want to find the matrix $U$ that minimizes the following loss function:
$$ \min_U( \max_{0 \le j \le t} (\operatorname{tr}(W_jU) + b_j) + \operatorname{tr}(U^TU)) $$

The given loss function is convex and piecewise linear, but not differentiable at all points. Is there some Python library or function that allows me to optmize the loss function over a matrix, because from my understanding `scipy.optimize.minimize` allows for minimization of vectors only.

Comment: just flatten the matrix into a vector